# Make: Snippet not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, makefile

I am trying do the following in a Makefile. For some reason I cannot get it to work right:

1. Get the first line of a file
2. Check if the line starts with '/'
3. If the line does not, prepend a path to every line in the file

Here is the code I have:

```
if test $${$(shell head -n 1 ./root/lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VERSION)/modules.dep):0:1} -ne '/' then \
    cat ./root/lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VERSION)/modules.dep | while read line; do echo "/lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VERSION)/$$line"; done > /tmp/modules.dep.new; \
    cp /tmp/modules.dep.new ./root/lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VERSION)/modules.dep; \
    rm /tmp/modules.dep.new; \
fi
```

The head command does not return anything. If I run head command alone, I get the first line of the file.

Comment: Not really addressing your problem, but what happens if you replace the head with "sed 1q"? Might help narrow down the issue. Also, are= you suare the cwd is where you think it is, and KERNEL_VERSION is defined?

Comment: @Paul: The path is almost certainly correct (cwd correct and KERNEL_VERSION defined) if he can get the first line of the file.

Comment: Not necessarily because he's only getting the first line when running the head command alone ("If I run head command alone, I get the first line of the file.") and when run in the Makefile he gets nothing ("
The head command does not return anything")

Comment: @Paul: You're right, I misread that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get your `if test a -ne b` approach to work (shell scripting isn't really my strongest hold), but personally I'd do it this way:

```
FILE = ./root/lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VERSION)/modules.dep

PREFIX = /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_VERSION)

foo:
  sed -i -e 'H;$$!d;x;s/.//;/^\//!{s|^|$(PREFIX)|;s|\n|\n$(PREFIX)|g}' $(FILE)
```

**EDIT:**

Come to think of it, this is a little more elegant:

```
  sed -i '1{h;s/\(.\).*/\1/;s/\//a$(PREFIX)/;s/.//;x};H;g;s/\n.*//;x;s/\n//' $(FILE)
```

**EDIT:**

Wait, this is even better:

```
@sed -i '1{/^\//!{x;s/^/$(PREFIX)/;x}};G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/' $(FILE)
```